# Print NSMutableURLRequest Contents

Tags: ios, nslog, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to ask if anybody has ever tried printing out the values of a NSMutableURLRequest *request;

Here's my scenario, I have formed my XML and tried sending it using Firefox Poster plugin, I am successful playing with valid and invalid contents, so its time to move into iOS, unfortunately with iOS it doesn't seem to work correctly tho I always get a response of Bad Request (400) which I suspect is caused by a malformed xml content; So I was thinking before sending the request I want to check if it's on its correct form.

So it boils down to "How can I print out (nslog, etc..) the content of the *request"

Sample code below:

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ps"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest                                         requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.xmlLogin length]];

    //NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[self xmlLogin]];
    [request addValue:@"application/xxx.ven.xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    [request setValue:@"windows-1251" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Charset"];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[self xmlLogin] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

this code snippet

```
NSLog(@"Request %@\n",request);
```

results to

```
<NSMutableURLRequest http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ps>
```

while doing something like

```
NSLog(@"Request %@\n",[request HTTPBody]);
```

results to

```
<4c697665 3e383634 30303c2f 54696d65 546f4c69 76653e20 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 203c5365 7373696f 6e436f6f 6b69653e 436f6c69 62726961 494d5053 5f333734 36323032 39322e34 38373931 345f3737 33313c2f 53657373 696f6e43 6f6f6b69 653e2020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 3c2f4c6f 67696e2d 52657175 6573743e 3c2f5472 616e7361 6374696f 6e436f6e 74656e74 3e3c2f54 72616e73 61637469 6f6e3e20 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 203c2f53 65737369 6f6e3e3c 2f57562d 4353502d 4d657373 6167653e>
```

I know this collection of hex values can be converted; how? (tho finding how is just a wish list)

The real issue boils to the contents of the request which I am eager to find out how to view the raw contents and examine if its really on its correct form.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use `NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 30):

```
NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: But if i want request with parameters in one string i.e final URL,
like.. "http://192.168.100.50:8022/LoginService.svc/GetloginDetailObj/"ALL TH E PARAMETERS"
how can i got in nslog ...?

Comment: the above trick is only applicable to PUT/POST requests. a GET request has the parameters in the URI

Comment: String(data: request!.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// ---- (but please unwrap request and HTTPBody safely if possible, I use this in the debugging console only!)

Answer (score 10):

```
- (NSString *)formatURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"---REQUEST------------------\n"];
    [message appendFormat:@"URL: %@\n",[request.URL description] ];
    [message appendFormat:@"METHOD: %@\n",[request HTTPMethod]];
    for (NSString *header in [request allHTTPHeaderFields])
    {
        [message appendFormat:@"%@: %@\n",header,[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:header]];
    }
    [message appendFormat:@"BODY: %@\n",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [message appendString:@"----------------------------\n"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message];
}

- (NSString *)formatURLResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response withData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responsestr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"---RESPONSE------------------\n"];
    [message appendFormat:@"URL: %@\n",[response.URL description] ];
    [message appendFormat:@"MIMEType: %@\n",response.MIMEType];
    [message appendFormat:@"Status Code: %ld\n",(long)response.statusCode];
    for (NSString *header in [[response allHeaderFields] allKeys])
    {
        [message appendFormat:@"%@: %@\n",header,[response allHeaderFields][header]];
    }
    [message appendFormat:@"Response Data: %@\n",responsestr];
    [message appendString:@"----------------------------\n"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message];
}
```