# Convenient way to print raw HTTP request in Swift or Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a convenient way to view or print a `NSMutableURLRequest` as a raw HTTP request -- i.e. how it gets sent over the wire? Perhaps when the request is actually made? I'm specifically **not** trying to extract specific components of the request and manually compose them together. FWIW I'm loading it in a webview with `WKWebView.loadRequest(r)`.

By raw request, I mean as it is sent over the wire -- something like:

```
POST /target/command HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 38914
Custom-Header: custom-value

{"param": "value"}
```

The reason I'm asking is because my server seems to receive an empty request body for a particular request, while it receives request bodies on others. Would be very useful if I could debug this like I debug on my server -- by printing the raw request. I understand I could use proxy tools like Charles, but I'm hoping there's a more convenient answer.

Comment: I guess you are asking for allHTTPHeaderFields of NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print NSMutableURLRequest Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375658/print-nsmutableurlrequest-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used RequestBin (requestb.in) instead to make sure I wasn't going crazy... Turns out there's a bug in `WKWebView.loadRequest(r)` where `r.HTTPBody` will not get passed in the request body even when non-nil. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I generally just print out all outgoing requests as a copy/pasteable cURL command with a category like this, you can probably reformat it if you don't need the functionality.

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (cURLRepresentation)

- (NSString *)escapeQuotesInString:(NSString *)string {
    NSParameterAssert(string.length);

    return [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
}

- (NSString *)cURLRepresentation {

    NSMutableString *curlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"-------\ncurl -k -X %@ --dump-header -", self.HTTPMethod];

    for (NSString *key in self.allHTTPHeaderFields.allKeys) {

        NSString *headerKey = [self escapeQuotesInString: key];
        NSString *headerValue = [self escapeQuotesInString: self.allHTTPHeaderFields[key] ];

        [curlString appendFormat:@" -H \"%@: %@\"", headerKey, headerValue];
    }

    NSString *bodyDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (bodyDataString.length) {

        bodyDataString = [self escapeQuotesInString: bodyDataString];
        [curlString appendFormat:@" -d \"%@\"", bodyDataString];
    }

    [curlString appendFormat:@" \"%@\"", self.URL.absoluteString];
    [curlString appendFormat:@"\n-------"];

    return curlString;
}

@end
```